# Find and replace keyword in entire HTML document using XPath

Tags: c#, html, xpath

I need to search the entire HTML document and highlight the keyword that I searched for. I'm using C# and XPath for the solution. I think I kind of have the solution, but the output is not what I desire.

```
static string keyword = "red";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string htmlString = @"<html>
                          <head>
                              <title>HTML sample page</title>
                          </head>
                          <body>
                              <div><div>This is inside div red paragraph</div></div>
                              <p>This is a red paragraph</p>
                              <p>This is a tes paragraph</p>
                              <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
                              <p>This is a paragraph red </p>
                          </body>
                          </html>";

    XmlDocument htmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    htmlDocument.Load(new StringReader(htmlString));

    foreach (XmlNode node in htmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*[contains(., 'red')]"))
    {
        node.InnerText = node.InnerText.Replace(keyword, "highlight" + keyword + "highlight");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(htmlDocument.InnerXml);
}
```

The output that I am getting looks like:

```
<html>HTML sample pageThis is inside div highlightredhighlight paragraphThis is a highlightredhighlight paragraphThis is a tes paragraphThis is a test paragraphThis is a paragraph highlightredhighlight </html>
```

The output seems to get rid of all the other tags besides the html tags. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The first match you get is the html tag because it contains red!! So you just replace all its content by its text with the extra highlight word.

Moreover if you really would need to highlight text you would need to split the text and insert a red (or something like that) node within.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
foreach (XmlNode node in htmlDocument.SelectNodes("//*[contains(text(), 'red')]"))
```

dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/iqBxeJ